# wrap jquery method doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var gethtml = $('.app-bar td:nth-child(1)').clone();

$('.arrow-back').after($(gethtml).wrap("<div></div>"));
```

I can see the html block but it's not wrapped within div, anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because .wrap() will not return the wrapped element(the `div`) instead it will return the jQuery obeject on which it was called on, so you are still appending only the contents of `gethtml`

```
$('.arrow-back').after($(gethtml).wrap("<div></div>").parent());
```

Another way to do the same is

```
$('<div />', {
    html: gethtml
}).insertAfter('.arrow-back')
```